# Deleting MongoDB Subdocuments By Id

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

EDIT:

Here's what the data looks like in my shell:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f3b29782ef1988ccd94f3"),
    "data" : {
        "fara" : {
            "names" : [ ],
            "enabled" : false,
            "tags" : [ ]
        },
        "senators" : {
            "names" : [
                "5d64511970ee667cc6fdd264",
                "5d64511970ee667cc6fdd265",
                "5d64511970ee667cc6fdd269",
                "5d64511970ee667cc6fdd263"
            ],
            "enabled" : false,
            "tags" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d706e3fe1bf18b4eb5385db"),
                    "row" : "5d64511970ee667cc6fdd263",
                    "data" : "hi"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d706f20550b97b588c78f31"),
                    "row" : "5d64511970ee667cc6fdd263",
                    "data" : "hello"
                }
                ....
```

I'm trying to delete subdocuments listed inside a document by id, in other words delete one of the tags subdocument (like the subdocument that says "hello"). The subdocuments are listed in the "tag" field of the data structure. I'm writing this in Node.js, if that's important.

The Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    data: {
      senators: {
        enabled: {
          type: Boolean
        },
        names: {
          type: Array
        },
        tags: [{
          id: {
            type: String
          },
          row: {
            type: String
          },
          data: {
            type: String
          }
        }]
      },
      senateCandidates: {
        enabled: {
          type: Boolean
        },
        names: {
          type: Array
        },
        tags: [{
          id: {
            type: String
          },
          row: {
            type: String
          },
          data: {
            type: String
          }
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

And I'm trying to simply delete a single sub-document within the "senators.tag" array based on the id. My route looks something like this:

```
deleteSenatorTag: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": req.params.id }, { /// $pull using req.param.tid? /// })
        res.status(200).send(); 
    } catch(err){
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || 'This tag could not be deleted.'
        })
    }
}
```

The params that I'm passing in include:

1) The id of the overall document, provided to the route as req.param.id

2) The id of the subdocument I want to delete, provided as req.param.tid

Both of these are just simple strings.

Is there any way that I can run a simple update function that deletes the subdocument based on the second parameter? I'm assuming it might be the $pull operator, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Mongoose** client and want to search/pull element by _id then, you need to convert an "_id" **String** into **Mongo ObjectId.** while forming a query.

From your data, I understand you are searching a document by _id and wants to pull an object from a tags array with matching tag _id.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id":  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    {
        $pull: {
            "data.senators.tags": {
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.param.tid)
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The above syntax will work, you can modify your tags search criteria according to your requirement in the above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": req.params.id },
    {
        $pull: {
            data: {
               senators: {
                   tags: {
                       id: req.param.tid
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: No luck. It's giving me the error, "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value." Additionally (should have mentioned in the original post) the "tid" is a string value, so I may need to convert it to an actual objectId? Or can I just use it as a string. I think that's a separate problem but wanted to make a note of it.

Comment: can you check if the id you're trying to pull i.e. req.param.tid exists or not in collection?

Comment: Since I'm using the mongoose system, the answer above worked. This may be for the shell?